# How to iterate active items

Tags: jquery

I have a problem iterating jquery elements in `<ul>` with jquery , the problem is that I have a simple menu and I need to get the value of the link when I do click in the link with `filter()` function.

```
<div class="panel-content">
<ul class=" filters-option">
<li class="category"><a value="1">CAT1<small>(722)</small></a></li>
<li class="category"><a value="2">CAT2<small>(722)</small></a></li>
<li class="category"><a value="3">CAT3<small>(722)</small></a></li>
</ul>
<a onclick="filter()" class="test button btn-mini col-md-12">Filtrar</a>
</div>
```

The following code

```
 function filter(){
           alert(tjq('ul.category li a'));
        }
```

How I can solve this problem ? Are there other possibles solutions?

Comment: What exactly is `tjq`?

Comment: probably jQuery noConflict https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Answer (score 1):

use [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to loop through these elements

```
function filter(){
  tjq('ul.category li a').each(function(){
    var val = $(this).attr('value');
    alert(val);
  });
}
```

Note that this is not a valid HTML, you should probably use data- attribute or href to store the value, but this still should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a.col-md-12").on("click",function(){

        $(".category a").each(function(){

            alert($(this).attr("value"));

        })

    })

})
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="panel-content">
            <ul class=" filters-option">
            <li class="category"><a value="1">CAT1<small>(722)</small></a></li>
            <li class="category"><a value="2">CAT2<small>(722)</small></a></li>
            <li class="category"><a value="3">CAT3<small>(722)</small></a></li>
            </ul>
            <a class="test button btn-mini col-md-12">Filtrar</a>
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("a.col-md-12").on("click",function(){

                $(".category a").each(function(){

                    alert($(this).attr("value"));

                })

            })

        })
            
       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```